# How can I check for specific strings in python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm used to doing Regex's in a variety of languages, but I don't know Python well.

I'm looking for a regex that will do the same as the following JavaScript regex:

```
(disc|dis|se|oti)(\d+)\W
```

i.e. where the string will consist of one of those 4 strings followed by one or more digits followed by a space. This string will appear at the very beginning of the string (so I can use re.match rather than re.search).

It looks like I can use this:

```
re.match( r'(disc|dis|se|oti)(\d+)\s', line)
```

but should I be using the 'r' at the beginning?

Comment: You could just use it as `re.match( r'(disc|dis|se|oti)(\d+)\W', line)` if you want. If you're trying to match anywhere in a string, then use `re.search` instead of `re.match`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `r` in the string means that the backslashes `\` in the string won't create unusual characters, so it's usually a good idea.

Also note you need to `import re` at the beginning of the program.

**Full code**

```
import re
match = re.match( r'(disc|dis|se|oti)(\d+)\s', line)
```

*or* omit the `r` before the string, and double all the backslashes:

```
import re
match = re.match( '(disc|dis|se|oti)(\\d+)\\s', line)
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Will help you understand about regex in python2.7